# Can we create 2 functions with same name in Codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there any way I can create 2 functions in Codeigniter controller where one of the function contains argument and the other doesn't. I am using the below code which is giving me an error.

```
class example extends CI_Controller {
    function show() {
        #code goes here
    }

   function show($id) {
       #code goes here
    }
}
```

But it's showing me an error that function name cannot be same.

Comment: So...the answer is "you can't". You cannot define the same function (or method) twice in PHP; your attempt at method overloading isn't supported in this language.

Comment: Why would you want that? :O

Comment: @f4der so I can pass the url with an id to show specified row on the page and if I dont pass any id, it will show me all the rows from the table.

Comment: In that case you should look at the answer of Alex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
function show($id = null)
{
    if ($id === null) {
        // $id was not passed
    } else {
        // $id was passed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP manual not:

> PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions.
> http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

However with Runkit it's possible to do so:

```
<?php
function testme() {
  echo "Original Testme Implementation\n";
}
testme();
runkit_function_redefine('testme','','echo "New Testme Implementation\n";');
testme();
?>
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php